# DataOutputStream: purpose of the "encoded string too long" restriction

Tags: java, restriction, dataoutputstream

There is a strange restriction in `java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(String str)` method, which limits the size of an UTF-8 encoded string to `65535` bytes:

```
    if (utflen > 65535)
        throw new UTFDataFormatException(
            "encoded string too long: " + utflen + " bytes");
```

It is strange, because:

1. there is no any information about this restriction in JavaDoc of this method
2. this restriction can be easily solved by copying and modifying an internal `static int writeUTF(String str, DataOutput out)`  method of this class
3. there is no such restriction in the opposite method `java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF()`.

According to the said above I can not understand the purpose of a such restriction in the `writeUTF` method. What have I missed or misunderstood?

Comment: It is an assumption that you would never need to send such a long string.  This class dates back to Java 1.2 and many assumptions were made in the early days which are not as valid today.  I have a similar method in a library of mine, but I use stop bit encoding for the length which means it uses a byte for each 7 bits of the length, so it is shorter in the common case, but can be 2 billion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Javadoc of `DataOutputStream.writeUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29) states:

> First, **two bytes** are written to the output stream as if by the
>   `writeShort` method giving the number of bytes to follow. This value
>   is the number of bytes actually written out, not the length of the
>   string.

Two bytes means 16 bits: in 16 bits the maximum integer one can encode is `2^16` == 65535.
[`DataInputStream.readUTF`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF%28%29) has the exact same restriction, because it first reads the number of UTF-8 bytes to consume, in the form of a 2-byte integer, which again can only have a maximum value of 65535.

---

`writeUTF` first writes two bytes with the length, which has the same result as calling `writeShort` with the length and then writing the UTF-encoded bytes. `writeUTF` doesn't actually call `writeShort` - it builds up a single `byte[]` with both the 2-byte length and the UTF bytes. But that is why the Javadoc says "**as if** by the `writeShort` method" rather than just "by the `writeShort` method".

Comment: This is actually wrong statement in JavaDoc: there is no any `writeShort` analogue in `writeUTF` method.

Comment: @Andremoniy added my response to the answer